# MySQL for Excel not working anymore - how to fix it?

Tags: excel

I hope someone has a solution for my strange problem. I was using MySQL for Excel until today. For some reason I got a blue-screen and after that, it is not working anymore... The Tab-Icon in Excel is still available, however, when clicking on it gets stuck in loading mode. (Turning wheel) There is no error message displayed.
Does anyone have an idea of how to fix this? I obviously tried uninstalling/installing already…

Thanks and Regards,
Daniel

uninstalling/installing - no change in behavior

Comment: Have you checked mysql service is running? Have you checked mysql is not broken by firing up an ide or from command line?

Comment: Yes, I  can get the data from my db by "retrieving external data" with excel or by connecting using MySQL Workbench